# AutoScaling EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm hoping to move an application to AWS.
I would like to use AutoScaling to lower the number of active EC2 instances when the application is under a lower load.

My problem is.....
I have one service account used for all communication between the various components of the application and the servers in that environment.

We have a security exception with my company which allows us to use the service account to perform its actions on each individual server.
Every time we introduce a new server to the environment, we have to request that the security team update our exception list to allow the new server in as well.

There is no automatic method for doing this. We have to submit a request to the security team asking for the new server to be added to the exception.

So while AutoScaling would be perfect, how can it work in this case if each time a server is added the security team needs to be notified so they can add the new server to the exception list?

Answer (score 1):

You can get [notifications when your autoscale group scales](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ASGettingNotifications.html) either up or down.  SNS can send a variety of things, including SMS (text) messages to a cell phone.

While this would work, it is incredibly manual.  The goal of an autoscale group is to let the environment expand and contract without human intervention.  I personally would not implement this as, depending on the availability of your security team they may be a bottle neck to scaling up.  If for some reason they miss the scale up event that signals them to do something then you've got orphan machines that you're paying for that are doing nothing.

Additionally, there are also ways to script the provisioning of a new machine.  Perhaps there is a way to add what you want automatically.  AWS calls this `userdata` - you can learn a bit more about it from the [AWS EC2 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html).

But ultimately I'd really take a step back and look at your architecture.  If you can't script the machine provisioning then autoscaling is not very worthwhile - it's just plain "have devops add another machine if needed and hope they remember to take it down when it's not needed".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. You confirm what I was thinking. The manual process (carried out by the Security team) will still need done and basically hampers autoscaling